# What is unique about this confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $y_1, y_2, \ldots , y_n$ is a random sample of size n from a normal distribution where 
$\sigma$ is known. Depending on how the tail-area probabilities are split up, an infinite number of random interval having a $95\%$ probability of containing
\mu can be constructed. What is unique about the particular interval
\begin{equation}
\left(\bar y−1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar  y+1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)?
\end{equation}

I can think of only three possible ways in which the interval in unique.

1. As $n$ increases, the size of the interval decreases while the confidence level remains the same.
2. $2.5\%$ of the probabilities lie in each one of the tails.
3. The interval is symmetric about the sample mean.

Are any of those correct?

Answer (score 3):

First, it is *not true* in the frequentist interpretation of confidence inervals that the *probability* that the confidence interval includes the mean is $0.95$.  That being said, the confidence interval that you list is the shortest confidence interval for the mean that you can find: all other confidence intervals will be longer. And yes, properties 1 and 3 are enjoyed by this confidence interval but
they are not unique in the sense that confidence intervals for other problems
(involving random variables that are not normal) may well also have these properties.

Comment: I would vote up, but I don't have enough reputation.